# Spring Integration JSON escape issue

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-integration, dsl

I have the listed the spring integration flow below to orchestrate 2 api's and aggregate the results and return as List. The work flow works as expected but the response is JSON escaped. I was to write message converters but not sure if that's right, any help here, please ?

Respone JSON :

```
[
   "{\"primaryCardNumber\":\"0002345235352345\"",
   "\"accountStatus\":\"A\"",
   "\"primaryCardSequence\":\"1234\"",
   "\"secondaryCardsNumber\":\"4\"",
   "\"additionalCardsNumber\":\"1\"",
   "\"lastPaymentDate\":\"2016-08-18\"",
   "\"billingCurrencyCode\":\"GBP\"}",
   "{\"primaryCardNumber\":\"00064545108761239\"",
   "\"accountStatus\":\"A\"",
   "\"primaryCardSequence\":\"4221\"",
   "\"secondaryCardsNumber\":\"1\"",
   "\"additionalCardsNumber\":\"0\"",
   "\"lastPaymentDate\":\"2015-12-01\"",
   "\"billingCurrencyCode\":\"GBP\"}"
]
```

Code:

```
    @MessagingGateway
    public interface AccountList {

       @Gateway(requestChannel = "accountListFlow.input")
       List<String> accountListFlow(String customerId);
    }

     @Bean
     public IntegrationFlow accountListFlow() {
            return flow -> flow.publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s.applySequence(true)
                                    .subscribe(f -> f
                                               .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("X-CUST-IP-Id","145.26.54.24"))      
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://get-customers-product-holdings-gb-hbeu-v3-v3-cert.cf.wgdc-drn-01.cloud.uk/api/customers/{customer}/product-holdings?categoryCode=cc,cbs,sd")
                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                .mappedRequestHeaders("X-CUST-IP-Id")
                .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                .uriVariable("customer", "payload")
                .extractPayload(true))
            .channel("aggregateAccount.input")
.subscribe(f -> f
                                           .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("X-CUST-IP-Id","145.26.54.24"))      
        .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://get-customers-product-holdings-gb-hbeu-v3-v3-cert.cf.wgdc-drn-01.cloud.uk/api/customers/{customer}/balances")
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .mappedRequestHeaders("X-CUST-IP-Id")
            .expectedResponseType(String.class)
            .uriVariable("customer", "payload")
            .extractPayload(true))
        .channel("aggregateAccount.input")
);
}           
      @Bean
      public IntegrationFlow aggregateAccount() {
         return flow -> flow
                .aggregate(a -> a.expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                               .outputProcessor(g -> g.getMessages()
                                            .stream()
                                            .filter(m -> m.getPayload() != null)
                                            .map(message-> message.getPayload().toString())
                                            .collect(Collectors.joining(","))));
                }
```

Comment: More info, please! Where do you see that result? How can you be sure that you are doing something wrong? How do those two results from the services look?

Comment: It's not "escaped" . You have an array with a single string, which happens to be json data itself

Comment: The flow is triggered from within a Spring REST controller which returns JSON and the result above is as seen from chrome or SOAPUI on invoking the URI.  Logging response of two API's onto console looks OK without json escape's.  And just a note that the response on my REST controller is List<String> and is the same result from aggregator is propgated until then. Hope this helps.

Comment: @cricket_007 , if i change from List<String> to String , i don't get aggregated message but just the first message.

Comment: ` @RequestMapping(value = "/account/list/{customerId}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
    public String accountList(
            @PathVariable String customerId) {

        return accountListGatewayGateway.accountListFlow(customerId);
    } `

Comment: You don't want a String or a list of strings... You want a list of serialized objects as JSON. Unfortunately, I can't tell where your error is without a [mcve]